# Split string and trim every element

Tags: java

Is there any library API or regex pattern to split a String on some delimiter and automatically trim leading and trailing spaces from every element without having to loop the elements?

For example, on splitting `"  A   B #  C#D# E  #  "` on `#` the desired output is `[A   B,C,D,E]`

The closest I got is `str.split("\\s*#\\s*")` which gives `[  A   B, C, D, E]`

Comment: Isn't that just a trick of `Arrays.toString()`? It works fine for me.

Comment: Well with your code you certainly wouldn't have to "loop the elements"; it's only the first and last elements that wouldn't be trimmed.

Comment: @Biziclop: I think Somu is referring to `A B` being ` A B` instead.  There is no delimiter at the start so the beginning isn't trimmed.

Comment: Just to clarify, the desired output is `String[]`. So when I say `[A B,C,D,E]`, I really meant `{"A B","C","D","E"}`

Comment: @Mark Peters Ah, I see what the problem is now. As far as I'm aware, `split()` can't trim that. You can do `"(^\\s+)|(\\s*#\\s*)|(\\s+$)"` but that would create an extra empty string at the start and the end.

Comment: So, what's wrong? Each element is trimmed, i.e. the spaces are removed. What result do you want to see?

Comment: @AlexR Yes, I tried the correct regex, but as biziclop and Garrett Hall pointed out, I was just misled by `Array.toString`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just trim it before you split

```
" A B # C#D# E # ".trim().split("\\s*#\\s*")
```

The spaces after the commas in `[ A B, C, D, E]` are just the way `Arrays.toString` prints

Comment: Thanks, this was silly of me, got fooled by `Arrays.toString`'s formatted output :)

Comment: @biziclop Yeah I took a second too long to decipher your comment. You were spot on! Thank you.

Comment: `" A B # C#D# E # ".trim().split("\\s*#\\s*")` is not working but `" A B # C#D# E # ".trim().split(\\s*#\\s*)`

Comment: This answer is OK. But I prefer regular expression like so `.split(/\s*#\s*/)`.

Answer (score 10):

Guava to the rescue!  Use [CharMatcher](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) and [Splitter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).  I use [Joiner](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) just to stitch the Iterable back together, clearly showing that the iterable only has the letters in it, with no padding, extraneous spaces, or hash signs.

```
package main;

import com.google.common.base.CharMatcher;
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;

public class TestMain {

    static Splitter split = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf(" #")).trimResults()
            .omitEmptyStrings();
    static Joiner join = Joiner.on(", ");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String test = " A B # C#D# E # ";
        System.out.println(join.join(split.split(test)));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A, B, C, D, E
```

Great for people who get headaches from regex.

Answer (score 3):

What about just doing a replaceall before splitting?

```
str.replaceall("\\s*#\\s*","#").split()
```

Comment: It gives the same result `[  A   B, C, D, E]`

Comment: I suppose you could do a trim() on the string after the replaceAll.

Answer (score 2):

Edited to correct whitespace error that was pointed out by Marcus.

I think that the proper regex should be [\s]*#[\s]*:

```
str.split("[\\s]*#[\\s]*");
```

Tested on : http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Why would `\\s` need to be in brackets?

Comment: Umm, because I'm an idiot :P
Yeah, you really don't need those.

Answer (score -1):

Without regex it should look like this:

```
"  A   B #  C#D# E  #  "
    .split('#')
    .map(function(item) { return item.trim(); } )
    .filter(function(n){ return n != "" });
```

outputs:
["A   B", "C", "D", "E"]

Comment: The question is tagged as Java :)