# Java - Split and trim in one shot

Tags: java, string, split, trim

I have a String like this :

```
String attributes = " foo boo, faa baa, fii bii,"
```

and I want to get a result like this :

```
String[] result = {"foo boo", "faa baa", "fii bii"};
```

So my issue is how should to make split and trim in one shot i already split:

```
String[] result = attributes.split(",");
```

But the `spaces` still in the result :

```
String[] result = {" foo boo", " faa baa", " fii bii"};
                    ^           ^           ^
```

I know that we can make a loop and make `trim` for every one but I want to makes it in shot.

Comment: you could also split on `,\\s` and remove the last `,` in your `String`

Comment: @KevinEsche Mind the leading space in first entry. This would have to be trimmed, too.

Comment: In my opinion, doing this in "two shots" would be the cleanest way to code it and not much more effort. I really don't see the point in over-complicating this.

Comment: I second Silverclaw. IMHO this is premature optimization. So long doing it in two steps will not lead to performance issues, do it in two steps. Not worth the effort, I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987149/split-string-and-trim-every-element

Comment: Globally string-replace `n spaces + delimiter + n spaces` with `delimiter`. Then do your simple split. I believe string-replace is extremely fast, compared to iteration of an array.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Use regular expression `\s*,\s*` for splitting.

```
String result[] = attributes.split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

---

**For Initial and Trailing Whitespaces**
The previous solution still leaves initial and trailing white-spaces. So if we're expecting any of them, then we can use the following solution to remove the same:

```
String result[] = attributes.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

Comment: Still it doesn't fall under single shot!!!! @YCF_L as trim is he first shot and split is the second shot!!!

Comment: @SASIKUMAR it can't never work without trim(). as split is just gonna segment the string not alter the segmentation.

Comment: @SASIKUMARS i think this is the better solution until now maybe we can wait to a better one ?

Comment: Yes basically you can never make it one shot as it has two different opertaions, even internally it should go for both ones @YCF_L?

Comment: Well, I guess this is as close as you can get without writing your own parser. And it is only 1 trim instead of n trims ...

Comment: Okay for splitting on a comma -- but you don't want this for tab-delimited input as it trims leading empty fields.

Comment: Would this solution work if the separator is a space?
attributes.trim().split("\\s* \\s*");

Comment: @RodrigoR.Coelho `\\s` itself will cover all the space characters. So in your case, you can just use `attributes.trim().split("\\s*");`

Answer (score 67):

Using java 8 you can do it like this in one line

```
String[] result = Arrays.stream(attributes.split(",")).map(String::trim).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: this is not one shot! i guess you are just writing for loop in one line

Comment: @SASIKUMARS Depends on your definition of "one shot". If equal to "one line" it is perfectly ok.

Comment: Oh. I did not understand that "one shot" properly... Sorry. :).
@Fildor I also thought about one line...

Comment: Sorry it doesn't make sense for the term "one shot" @Fildor

Comment: @SASIKUMARS I disagree. Me, too I interpreted it as "in one **step**" but that doesn't mean other interpretations are not valid.

Comment: I didnt mean it not valid. Its not the best solution... But it is a good solution even though!!! @Fildor

Comment: OK, I can agree with that @SASIKUMARS

Comment: Nice solution. It's usually better to go without regexes. What does `.toArray(String[]::new)` mean?

Comment: @MikhailBatcer The `String[]::new`part is basically a function which produces a new array of the desired type and the provided length. And the method itself `toArray()` returnes an array containing the elements of the stream by making use of the above specified function.

Answer (score 4):

If there is no text between the commas, the following expression will not create empty elements:

```
String result[] = attributes.trim().split("\\s*,+\\s*,*\\s*");
```

Comment: nice try. `⠀⠀⠀`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with Google Guava library this way :

```
List<String> results = Splitter.on(",").trimResults().splitToList(attributes);
```

which I find quite elegant as the code is very explicit in what it does when you read it.

Answer (score 2):

ApaceCommons StringUtils.stripAll function can be used to trim individual elements of an array. It leaves the null as null if some of your array elements are null.

Here,

```
String[] array = StringUtils.stripAll(attributes.split(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

create your own custom function

```
private static String[] split_and_trim_in_one_shot(String string){
 String[] result  = string.split(",");
 int array_length = result.length;

 for(int i =0; i < array_length ; i++){
  result[i]=result[i].trim();
 }
 return result;
```

Overload with a consideration for custom delimiter

```
private static String[] split_and_trim_in_one_shot(String string, String delimiter){
 String[] result  = string.split(delimiter);
 int array_length = result.length;

 for(int i =0; i < array_length ; i++){
  result[i]=result[i].trim();
 }
 return result;
```

with streams

```
public static List<String> split(String str){
return Stream.of(str.split(","))
  .map(String::trim)
  .map (elem -> new String(elem))//optional
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

What about spliting with comma and space:

```
String result[] = attributes.split(",\\s");
```

Comment: This would still need special treatment of first and last entry. Not a problem but just saying. So it wouldn't be really a "one-shot" neither.

Comment: this return a result like this space in begining and , in the end` foo boo
faa baa
fii bii,`

Comment: @YCF_L Still, this drops your effort to trimming result[0] and removing a "," from result[result.length-1] instead of touching each element.

Comment: good idea! But what if there are more than one space? How to split on multiple spaces?

Answer (score 0):

```
String result[] = attributes.trim().split("\\s*,[,\\s]*");
```

previously posted here: https://blog.oio.de/2012/08/23/split-comma-separated-strings-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

```java
// given input
String attributes = " foo boo, faa baa, fii bii,";

// desired output
String[] result = {"foo boo", "faa baa", "fii bii"};
```

This should work:

```java
String[] s = attributes.trim().split("[,]");
```

As answered by @Raman Sahasi:

> before you split your string, you can trim the trailing and leading spaces. I've used the delimiter `,` as it was your only delimiter in your string

Comment: nope! it keeps the leading spaces of faa and fii !!!

Comment: with grovy and the trailing asterisk operator will apply any trailing operation to each of the elements: attributes.split("[,]")*.trim() (hoping that will be still read-able with the mini-format codes here in the comments)

Answer (score -2):

Best way is:

```
value.split(",").map(function(x) {return x.trim()});
```