# SPEL - Split and trim, de-limited values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I am trying to split String values based on de-limiter and trim them before putting them in a list.

I am able to split the values, could you please suggest how can be trim the list.

```
@Value("#{'${string-values}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> textList;
```

The problem it seems is, Split returns a list and I need to invoke trim() before storing them in the variable.

Comment: It's best not to use injection annotations like `@Value` on fields anyway. Instead, inject as a constructor parameter and use the usual techniques there.

Answer (score 2):

Check
[Java - Split and trim in one shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953388/java-split-and-trim-in-one-shot/41953571)

```
@Value("#{'${string-values}'.split('\\s*,\\s*')}")
private List<String> textList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to provide no space between values in properties file.

To put a check in code it can be done in this way.

```
private List<String> textList;

public YourController(@Value("${string-values}") String propertyFromFile) {
        this.textList = new ArrayList<>(); 
        Arrays.asList(propertyFromFile.split(",")).forEach(b-> this.textList.add(b.trim()));        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be better to use @Configuration and then process that instead of doing like this, however you can add a new annotation on top of value annotation and use that annotation to process the list. For example

```
@Target(value = {ElementType.TYPE})
@Value
public @interface Trim {
 //Override the method you want to override
}

Public TrimPricessor {

//Implement the annotation method here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Spring Boot, use:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo.bar")
public class MyConfig {

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getList() {
        return this.list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

```
foo.bar.list=      a   ,   b,    c
```

The list entries are trimmed.